# Cloning a table MYSQL and adding a unique ID?

Tags: mysql, database, cloning

The code I have been using to clone a table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

However, there is a problem that in the new table I want a unique, auto incrementing id column.

But I run into the `column count doesn't match value count at row 1 error`.

I know that you can use the `DEFAULT keyword`, or leave the id out and it will auto increment but I am unsure as how the query should be structured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you added the PK auto increment column (assuming its the first column) try this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT NULL,[all column names from original_table] FROM original_table;
```